# Handle deselect row in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to handle case when user deselect row (that already selected) by tap on this row. It is well known that `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` / `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate methods not called in this case: they are called only if you tap on other, unselected yet row (my table view have single selection mode).

`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method also not called when I am deselecting row.

Is there is any easy solutions?

**Update**

The problem was in `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, where I return `nil` in some cases, thats why `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` didn't call. Thanks @Nekto for useful information and helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple docs say next about `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

> This method isn’t called when the editing property of the table is set to YES (that is, the table view is in editing mode).

That means that this method should be called unless your code has a bug or you haven't updated `delegate` of your table view or table is in editing mode.

One of the possible problems could be that you have incorrectly implemented `- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and are returning `nil` for the selected row. In that case `didSelect...` isn't called:

> Return nil if you don’t want the row deselected.

Alternatively you can implement another table view delegate method: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

> Tells the delegate that the highlight was removed from the row at the specified index path.

See more about managing selections in table views [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9).

Answer (score 1):

I have such use case. Why you don't create a variable for `lastSelectedRow`(here I have problem if it was `NSIndexPath` and I used two integers) and on the method for selecting row just compare `currentSelectedRow` with `lastSelectedRow`.

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called

Comment: You can have one gesture in the controller and add it and remove it on didSelectRowAtIndexPath but this is not good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, just use it like a check mark system would work.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30059704/6481734) explains how to use a checkmark. You can use this, or use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625307/6481734).

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called

Comment: That is because you have already selected it... I highly recommend using the checkmark.

Comment: But at link you provided they use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Am I wrong?

Comment: Wait it is never being called for you? If so there is a problem with your code

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath called when I select new, unselected row. didDeselectRowAtIndexPath called, when I deselect row by selecting other row. None of this methods called when I deselect row by tapping on selected row

Comment: I fully understand now, and I have an idea... Instead of isSelected, change the background color but still deselectRowAtIndexPath, then didSelectRowAtIndexPath will still be called, and then you can change the background color back to white or whatever it was originally.